# DAX function to calculate average based on ID and dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to calculate a 3 month average based on date and a change flag.
For example, I have columns:

Date - ID item - Description - Sales Amount - Change (shows 1 when the name has change)

It's possible to calculate average taking in consideration the change column and date, for example the product name was changed on may 2019 so I want to have the average 3 months after may and 3 months before may.

The image shows the table I'm using:

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output from the given sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correct, following this below steps will take you to your desired output-

**Step-1** Go to **Power Query Editor** and create 3 custom column as below-

```
start date before = Date.AddMonths([date],-2)
```

```
end date after = Date.AddMonths([date],3)
```

Change data type as Date after creating both custom columns and get back to report by clicking **Close & Apply** button.

**Step-2** Create these below 2 **Measure** in your table. I have considered the table name as **your_table_name** (adjust your self)

```
3_month_average_before = 

VAR current_row_chaneg = MIN(your_table_name[change])
VAR current_row_start_date_before = MIN(your_table_name[start date before])
VAR current_row_date = MIN(your_table_name[date])
VAR current_row_desc = MIN(your_table_name[desc.])

RETURN
IF(
    current_row_chaneg <> 1,
    BLANK(),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(your_table_name[sales]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(your_table_name),
            your_table_name[date] >= current_row_start_date_before
            && your_table_name[date] <= current_row_date
            && your_table_name[desc.] <> current_row_desc //--considered different product name for previous 3 month average
        )
    )
)
```

```
3_month_average_after = 

VAR current_row_chaneg = MIN(your_table_name[change])
VAR current_row_end_date_after = MIN(your_table_name[end date after])
VAR current_row_date = MIN(your_table_name[date])
VAR current_row_desc = MIN(your_table_name[desc.])

RETURN
IF(
    current_row_chaneg <> 1,
    BLANK(),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(your_table_name[sales]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(your_table_name),
            your_table_name[date] <= current_row_end_date_after
            && your_table_name[date] > current_row_date
            && your_table_name[desc.] = current_row_desc //--considered same product name for after 3 month average
        )
    )
)
```

I have applied logics based on my understanding. You can adjust logic if required in the same process. Here below is the sample output from your given sample data-

[image]

## Code for Column

```
change = 

VAR current_id  = your_table_name[id item]
VAR current_desc  = your_table_name[desc.]
VAR current_date  = your_table_name[date]

VAR current_item_count = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(your_table_name),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[id item] = current_id
        && your_table_name[desc.] = current_desc
        && your_table_name[date] <=current_date
    )
)

VAR previous_item_count = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(your_table_name),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[id item] = current_id
        && your_table_name[date] <= current_date
        && your_table_name[desc.] <> current_desc
    )
)

RETURN IF(current_item_count = 1 && previous_item_count <> 0 , 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks R_R, that is the outcome that I was looking for. Only one more thing I forgot to describe, the [change] column its a Dax measure, do you recommend I add [change] as a column with Power Query? Because as it is when I use the MIN expression, gives an error

Comment: There are differences in coding for Measure and Custom Column. If you can show the code for Measure you written, I can help adjusting the code for a Column. But as you said adding the column in Power Query, if you can do that, this is the better approach considering most cases.

Comment: I tried to add column without success, the measure for the change flag is:ChangeFlag = 
VAR FirstProduct = MINX(test,test[desc.])
VAR LastProduct = 
    MINX(
        FILTER(
            ALL(Test),
            test[id item] = MAX(test[id Item]) && 
            EDATE(DATE(test[Year],test[Month],1),1) = DATE(MAX(test[Year]),MAX(test[Month]),1)
            ),[Game])
RETURN 
    IF(
        FirstProduct<>LastProduct && NOT ISBLANK(LastProduct),
        1,
        0)

Comment: Missing Game column in your sample data.

Comment: Sorry, the instead of [Game] is [desc.]

Comment: @CarlosAguilar please check my suggested Column code added to the answer. you can also give me a up vote if it really helped :)

Comment: Thanks, only shows me error on the first lines VAR current_id  = your_table_name[id item], TOken Eof expected

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was adding the column on the Power Query, I add it on the add column and it worked just perfectly. one quick question, when do I need to use power query add column and the one its in the Power Bi menu? thanks for everything

Comment: In Power Query - that is output of transformation from different other columns and values. In Power BI Menu, it is a calculated column. Often you can achieve most of the output using both way. But you need to decide based on usability and performance that which way you will follow.